# How to put an icon for my android app using kivy-buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, appicon

I made an android app using python-kivy (Buildozer make it to apk file)

Now I want to put an image for the icon of the application. I mean the picture for the app-icon on your phone.

how can I do this? I cannot find any code in kv

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment `icon.filename:` in the buildozer spec file and write a path to your icon image.

Comment: what's the proper syntax for the path? When I enter the name of the image I get errors. do put the whole entire path (including the c drive, for instance)? I'm on Windows, btw.

Answer (score 0):

i presume you are using ubuntu for the build purpose , so u need to define the path as per linux naming convention , ideally keep it in the same path as the app file so that you don't to worry about the whole path.